# three.js - How to make particles always face up?

Tags: three.js

I am using THREE.Points to render a lot of particles.
The particles have a bill-boarded effect (by default).
I would like for all of my particles to face up (instead of the camera).
How can this be achieved?

Comment: I think you need to clarify what you meant by face up.

Comment: A bill-board always faces the camera. But instead of facing the camera I would like for it to face up. In other words, it does not rotate to adjust to the camera. It'll look like a square tile sitting on the floor.

Comment: what you are looking for is a regular THREE.PlaneGeometry rotated 90 degrees in x axis.

Comment: regarding this PlaneGeometry thing. I understand I can use it. But would it perform as well as a Particle System?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use THREE.PlaneGeometry instead.

Comment: But doesn't PlaneGeometry have a infinite width and length? I want small squares.

Comment: You can set the size of PlaneGeometry like so:  var geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(width, height);

Comment: regarding this PlaneGeometry thing. I understand I can use it. But would it perform as well as a Particle System?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I don't think the difference will be much. A plane is just 2 faces (2 triangles).

Comment: A plane is only 2 triangles. But in a particle system we could be talking about thousands of particles. If this is not buffered or merged into a single geometry it could quickly slow down the performance.

Comment: That is correct. If you don't need to move the planes, then it's a good idea to merge it into a single geometry.